# Magento 1.9 Configurable Products Options and cart issue

Tags: magento-1.9, php, configurable-product, configurable-swatches

I'm working on a magento 1.9 site, it have strange issue, we we go to a configurable product page it don't show the product options and ad to cart button.

-The list pages show the other two option images when mouse over.

-Can't see any js errors on console

-The product type also detect as configurable on product page.

-i also tried by apply default theme, it also same results.

-also checked stock and other things those seems fine.

**List Page**

[image]

Product Page
[image]

Anyone have a idea about this kind of issue

Comment: Can you check the container in your layout xml file? There should be 2 container through which custom options and configurable options are rendered. Also check the view.phtml if somehow the getChildHtml('') if containers are calling from there or not.

Comment: @SukumarGorai i tried to replace those with original base theme files both theme and phtml but still not showing options or cart button, very strange issue

Comment: Have you checked if the simple products associated with configurable products have inventory greater than 0 and products are in stock?

Comment: @Dexter yep, stock manage enabled, qty 100 and in stock